# Can I find date-picker library similar to this design please?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am searching for date-bicker JavaScript or jQuery library that the design is close to this screenshot https://ibb.co/D9trdgH

any help will be appreciated Thanks ^_^

Comment: Can't you implement something similar using Bootstrap? It shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there the closest thing I found it is this script I hope will help you: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/zyVjE/)

```
 $('#demo').mobipick({
    dateFormat: "MM-dd-yyyy"
});
```